# Integrating a half-normal pdf

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, distributions

The PDF of the half-normal distribution is:

$$f(x;\sigma)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sigma\sqrt{\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)\,\quad x>0\,.$$

The integral
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x;\sigma)\mathrm{d}x=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sigma\sqrt{\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)\mathrm{d}x$$

should be equal to one. The code used to check this:

```
Integrate[(Sqrt[2/Pi]/s)*Exp[-(x^2)/(2*s^2)], {x, 0, Infinity},
    Assumptions -> Re[s^2] > 0]
```

*Mathematica* gives $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sigma}}$ which doesn't make sense. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: And it is equal to $1$.

Comment: See the Mathematica code I added to the question.

Comment: Luckily not my problem, I can't afford Mathematica. Conceivably a bug. More likely an input typo.

Answer (score 8):

Using `Assuming[Element[s, Reals] && s > 0, ...]` tells *Mathematica* that `Re[s^2]>1` and also `s` itself is real to allow it to simplify final result to `1`.

*Mathematica* did not simplify $\sqrt{\frac{1}{s^2}}$ to $\frac{1}{s}$ since it did not know if $s$ was real or not and if it was real, if it is positive or not. That is why you did not get the result `1` expected.

```
Assuming[Element[s, Reals] && s > 0, Integrate[(Sqrt[2/Pi]/s)*Exp[-(x^2)/(2*s^2)], 
     {x, 0, Infinity}]]

(* 1 *)
```

Comment: thanks this is the right answer, but for this OP, it might be helpful to provide a bit more textual explanation.

Comment: Take `s` in the denominator outside the integral and you need no assumptions.  It just gives `1`.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some variants:

```
td = TruncatedDistribution[{0, Infinity}, NormalDistribution[0, s]];
Assuming[Element[s, Reals] && s > 0, 
Integrate[Sqrt[2/Pi] Exp[-x^2/(2 s^2)]/s, {x, 0, Infinity}]]
Integrate[Sqrt[2/Pi] Exp[-x^2/(2 s^2)]/s, {x, 0, Infinity}, 
 Assumptions -> {Element[s, Reals], s > 0}]
Integrate[PDF[td, x], {x, 0, Infinity}, 
 Assumptions -> {Element[s, Reals], s > 0}]
Integrate[
 PDF[HalfNormalDistribution[Sqrt[2/Pi]/s], x], {x, 0, Infinity}, 
 Assumptions -> {Element[s, Reals], s > 0}]
```

Note all the integrals yield 1. As @Nasser has observed the assumptions need to be declared.